# R Tidyverse totals per groups in dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

Having a df like this:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), V2 = c(5L, 
5L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Using tidyverse how can I get cumulative for V2 based on V1 such that I get

```
V1 V2 V3
A  5  18
A  5  18 
A  8  18
B  2  12
B  9  12
B  1  12
```

So I´m getting the total sum per group as a new variable.

Thx!

Comment: `df %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(V3 = sum(V2))`

Comment: `df %>% groupby(V1) %>% mutate(V3=sum(V2)`. Please search thoroughly next time. This has been discussed multiple times.

Comment: @slava-kohut: Did you forget `ungroup()` ?

Comment: @krlmlr No. `ungroup` is not needed (but doesn't hurt to have) if no further actions are to be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,V3:=sum(V2),by="V1"]
df[]
```

The code loads the `data.table` package, coerces `df` to type `data.table` by reference, takes a sum of `V2` in groups of `V1` and assigns the result back to a new column in `df` called `V3`.
`df[]` just prints the result.

Comment: Provide an explanation for your answer

Comment: @ShaluTD the code loads the `data.table` package, coerces `df` to type `data.table` by reference, takes a sum of `V2` in groups of `V1` and assigns the result back to a new column in `df` called `V3`. `df[]` just prints the result.